# Why does class autoloading not work for a package required using "repositories.package"?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

Consider two scenarios:

In the first the library is loaded from Github, `composer.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "revenuewire/ach-file": "*"
    }
}
```

composer libraries are downloaded with this command:

```
php composer update
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
require '../composer/vendor/autoload.php';
$achFileHeaderRecord = new \RW\ACH\FileHeaderRecord([
    // Required
    \RW\ACH\FileHeaderRecord::IMMEDIATE_DESTINATION => ' 123456789',
    \RW\ACH\FileHeaderRecord::IMMEDIATE_ORIGIN      => '1234567890',
    \RW\ACH\FileHeaderRecord::DESTINATION_NAME      => 'DESTNAME',
    \RW\ACH\FileHeaderRecord::ORIGIN_NAME           => 'Orig Name',
    // Optional
    \RW\ACH\FileHeaderRecord::FILE_DATE             => new DateTime(),
    \RW\ACH\FileHeaderRecord::FILE_ID_MODIFIER      => 'A',
    \RW\ACH\FileHeaderRecord::REFERENCE_CODE        => '',
]);
?>
```

This code will run successfully.

But when I try to load the **exactly** same library from Gitlab, `composer.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "repositories": [
      {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
          "name": "mygitlab/ach-file",
          "version": "1.2",
          "type": "package",
          "source": {
              "url": "https://mygitlab.ca/mygitlab/ach-file.git",
              "type": "git",
              "reference": "master"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "require": {
        "mygitlab/ach-file": "*"
    }
}
```

And now run the same code I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'RW\ACH\FileHeaderRecord' not found

This is caused because the library is not autoloaded.
It can be solved by adding this line, to load it manually:

```
require '../composer/vendor/aptpayapi/ach-file/bootstrap.php';
```

So in the case it is loaded as external package it does not read/execute the library's `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "revenuewire/ach-file",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Create and read ACH Payment files",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/revenuewire/ach-payment-file",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Matthew Casiro",
            "email": "mattcasiro@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "RW\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "RW\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "ext-ssh2": "*",
        "ext-bcmath": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.5"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to force autoload of externally loaded packages?

Comment: It seems that `https://mygitlab.ca` is not accessible. Is that only for demonstration? How does composer.json looks inside that repo?

Comment: @Justinas yes, that is just for demonstration because i cannot give anyone access to a private corporate gitlab repository. The `composer.json` is exactly the same as in the public one. For the purpose of this example you can consider the whole repository exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that by using a `package` key for that repository, you are telling composer "read the package information from *here*, do not read the hosted `composer.json`". And since the `package` settings are almost bare, dependencies are not resolved and autoloader not generated.

The only thing that happens is that composer clones the repo within your vendor, then you are on your own.

You *could* add an `autoload` section to your current `package` key, as shown [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2). This way you could at least have the autoloader correctly generated.

But note that recursive dependency resolution will not be dealt with, which might leave you with other issues.

For that you could replicate the `require` part of the original `composer.json` within the `package` setting... but this is not smart. The `package` key is meant for packages that **do not support Composer**, so you can force them into supporting it within your application. You'd end with something like this:

```json
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "mygitlab/ach-file",
        "version": "1.2",
        "type": "package",
        "autoload": {
          "psr-4": {
            "RW\\": "src/"
          }
        }, 
         "require": {
                "ext-ssh2": "*",
                "ext-bcmath": "*"
            },
        "source": {
          "url": "https://mygitlab.ca/mygitlab/ach-file.git",
          "type": "git",
          "reference": "master"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "mygitlab/ach-file": "*"
  }
}
```

Frankly, I wouldn't recommend this for a forked composer package. If what you want is use a fork of an existing package, do not use the `package` key at all.

Simply add the repository configuration, and require the forked package **by its original name** (`revenuewire/ach-file` in this case). Replace the version by `dev-master` (or whatever branch you use to hold your fork), and voilà, everything will work as usual because the library will be required as a regular composer package.

```json
{
 "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/yivi/ach-file"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "revenuewire/ach-file": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works. But you are perfectly right about the dependencies. While its not a problem with this library. It causes problems with another library, which was deleted from github, so i cannot include it. Is there a way to force composer to resolve the package's `composer.json`?

Comment: There are two ways: either you recreate the whole original `composer.json` in the `package` key (including `require`), or you do as I say in my second suggestion. **Do not use the `package` setting at all**. Simply use the `repository` key and refer to the package by its original name. Then the `composer.json`  file in the forked repo will be used.